# Check if a specific format of string is between specific parameters

Tags: java

I have gone through several post and could not find why my code is not working ok.

I have to ask the user to input a string through console with the following format.

[CapitalLeter][Number]

Where the letter must be A,B,C,D,E or F, and the number between 1 and 6.

This is my code.

```
        while ((x.length() != 2) || (x.charAt(0)>='F' && x.charAt(0)<='A') || (Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(1))>=6 && Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(1))<=1))
{
        System.out.println(msg);
        x = (new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();
    }
```

If I give it for example 3F it will accept it, and its wrong.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: You're using && when you should be using ||. `(x.charAt(0)>='F' && x.charAt(0)<='A')` is an impossible condition: a letter can't possibly be greater than F and smaller than A at the same time.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I changed that on the other condition too and worked.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a regexp like this: `if (x.matches("[A-F][1-6]")) { /* ok */ } else { /* not ok*/}`

Comment: You probably don't want to use `Character.getNumericValue`. It will accept Unicode characters representing Roman numerals (such as Ⅰ for 1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since OP answered himself I'll just copy-paste a commend made by @lospejos, which I think is a way better solution than the one proposed by OP (just for future generations sake)

```
if (matchesFormat(input)) {
    /* ok */ 
} else { 
    /* not ok */
}
```

with a helper method

```
boolean matchesFormat(String input) {
    return input.matches("[A-F][1-6]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using && when I should be using ||, fixed.

Thanks